# Eclipse and java 7 but no javac?

Tags: java, compiling, openjdk, jdk, sdk

I have a java computer program that I can compile in Eclipse just fine. I want to compile it from the command line and get the message `javac not found`. I figured that I just didn't have my path setup right, but then I did a `locate javac` and I only get:

> /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/javac
>   /usr/share/vim/vim74/compiler/javac.vim
>   /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/javacc.vim

and it does not exist in

> /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/

In Eclipse, it looks like it is using this JDK, so I am not sure how to account for how Eclipse compiles. Am I missing something silly? Thanks.

Comment: what is the output of 'javac -version' in the terminal?

Comment: That is just the problem - it can't find the command. But Eclipse must be using it somewhere, right?

Comment: I think Eclipse comes with a inbuilt compiler... so you might want to install jdk manually to run Java programs using the terminal.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like my default install came with some weird version of Java - not the OpenJDK but even another version. I did an aptitude install to get the openjdk-7 and then everything worked fine.

I was confused because Eclipse compiled without a javac on the system, but I guess Eclipse has some tools inside that allow it to compile.

Answer (score 1):

The default Java *runtime* environment (JRE) on Ubuntu is OpenJDK (instead of Oracle/Sun). Unlike the name OpenJDK this comes as two parts: a JRE (`default-jre`) and a JDK (`default-jdk`).

To also install the JDK (providing `javac`), install the metapackage [default-jdk [image: Install default-jdk]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/default-jdk) and you should be all set.

In case you have more than one Java runtime or Java compiler installed, select the right one with `update-alternatives`:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java   # runtime
sudo update-alternatives --config javaws # runtime Web Start (applets)
sudo update-alternatives --config javac  # compiler
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the openjdk you are using isn`t a jdk(besides the name). It is just a jvm (it can run java programs but not compile them).

My solution was download the jdk from oracle site: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

(this link is for jdk7, if you need another version just look for jdk in the site).